# Are upward directed set equivalent to downward directed set ? Example with $\supseteq$ and its dual relation $\subseteq$

Tags: relations, riemann-sum, nets

If the set of partitions of $[a,b]$ $S$ is taken as the directed set, along with the order $\subseteq$, then the directed set has the property that "for every pair $(c,d)$ in the directed set there is a **lower bound** $e$ in the directed set (such that $e\subseteq c$ and $e\subseteq d$)". In this case, if we write $$U(P,f) = \sum_{i=1} ^n M_i (x_i - x_{i-1})$$ where $M_i=sup_{[x_i, x_{i-1}]}(f)$ and $P=(x_0 =a,...,x_i,..., x_n =b)$ we note that $(U_P)_{P\in S}$ is **decreasing**.

On the other hand, if we take the same directed set but with the little change that the order is now $\supseteq$. Then, the directed set has the property that "for every pair $(c,d)$ in the directed set there is an **upper bound** $e$ in the directed set (such that $c\supseteq e$ and $d\supseteq e$). And now the same $(U_P)_{P\in S}$ is **increasing**.

My question is: are upward directed set equivalent to downward directed set ? After all, we just have to switch the order relation to it's dual in order to get something equivalent ?

I am asking because the introduction of the [Wikipedia article on directed sets](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Directed_set) let's think that these notions are not equivalent. "*Other authors call a set directed if and only if it is directed both upward and downward.*" This sentence let's me think they are not equivalent.

One possible attempt to answer my question is that maybe we don't always have a dual to an order relation ?

Thanks in advance